# How to make one column to take all the remaining width?

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j40recob/

I need the third div to stretch the remaining width (100%). Tried several solutions like `float:left` on the other two divs, but it didn't work. And if I set the third div itself on 100%, it displays below the other two divs but it should remain on the same line.

```css
.ui-tablewrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 0;
}
.ui-tablebanner {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1px;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: .75rem;
}
#ui-tablebanner-30 {
    width: 30px;
}
#ui-tablebanner-26 {
    width: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-tablewrapper">
    <div class="ui-tablebanner" id="ui-tablebanner-30">1</div>
    <div class="ui-tablebanner" id="ui-tablebanner-26">2</div>
    <div class="ui-tablebanner" id="ui-tablebanner">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the most up-to-date method, it's `flexbox`.

```css
.ui-tablewrapper {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}
.ui-tablebanner {
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: .75rem;
  flex: 0 0 auto
}
#ui-tablebanner-26 {
  flex-basis: 26px;
  background: red;
}
#ui-tablebanner-30 {
  flex-basis: 30px;
  background: blue;
}
#ui-tablebanner {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-tablewrapper">
  <div class="ui-tablebanner" id="ui-tablebanner-30">1</div>
  <div class="ui-tablebanner" id="ui-tablebanner-26">2</div>
  <div class="ui-tablebanner" id="ui-tablebanner">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1** - using `float`. Set the first 2 items to `float:left` and the 3rd one with `overflow:auto`. Browser support is super **IE6+**.

```css
.row {
    overflow: auto;
}
.item {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-right: 1px;
    width: 30px;
}
.item:last-child {
    float: none;
    overflow: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

**Approach 2** - using CSS `table` layout. The last cell will occupy all the available width automatically. Browser support is great **IE8+**.

```css
.row {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 1px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.item {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 30px;
}
.item:last-child {
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

**Approach 3** - using `inline-block` and `calc()`, and do the math, be aware that any border, padding, and margin are all counted. Browser support is good **IE9+**.

```css
.row {
    font-size: 0; /*remove inline gaps*/
}
.item {
    font-size: 16px; /*reset font size*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-right: 1px;
    width: 30px;
}
.item:last-child {
    width: calc(100% - 68px); /*do the math*/
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely position the blocks, setting the left edge of each and the right edge of the last block to 0:

```
.ui-tablebanner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
}

#ui-tablebanner-26 {
    width: 26px;
    left: 31px;

}

#ui-tablebanner-30 {
    width: 30px;
    left: 0;
}

#ui-tablebanner {
    left: 58px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7tgfmou2/1/

As an aside, I would also recommend using `box-sizing: border-box` to make width calculations easier, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing. And a CSS preprocessor like Sass, http://sass-lang.com/, to allow you to use variables in your position calculations. Example: `#ui-tablebanner { left: $banner-26-width + $banner-30-width + ($banner-margin*2);...`