# How to set full auto width for input tag

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements inline, first is span with image and defined with using padding left and right, I don't want to resize her width, just only like now width padding left and right.

My problem is on different resolution to fit this 3 inline element to be fit to container full 100% width.

How to set resizable width for INPUT on different resolution.

On small resolution I may to write new smaller width for INPUT tag.

Is it possible to set resizable input tag.

I want three elements to be 100% width in container of 90%, without resizing span elements, only INPUT.

I tried for this set width:78% of input tag, but thats it for large resolution, how to set for all resolution?

Is it posible to do using only HTML and CSS??

https://jsfiddle.net/4654eaue/4/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span><img src="http://science.psu.edu/alert/icons/video-iconSmall.png"></span><input type="text" name="fname" value="John Doe" disabled class="profileusername bordertop"><span><img src="http://science.psu.edu/alert/icons/video-iconSmall.png"></span>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width:90%;
}
input{
    width:78%;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    height:23px;
}
span img{
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
span{
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:grey;
}
```

Comment: About that images... did they must be one bellow other or on both side of input?

Comment: From both side of input.
ty

Comment: ok.... is it acceptable for You to put those spans and input in 3 separated divs?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18963730/4059974

Comment: look this jsfiddle (spans are removed and input is placed in div) : https://jsfiddle.net/4654eaue/6/

Comment: [How to make one column to take all the remaining width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502449/how-to-make-one-column-to-take-all-the-remaining-width)

Comment: I modified, now input tag is resizable, but when resizing my right image pops down :( https://jsfiddle.net/4654eaue/8/

Comment: @RS92 Take a look at my answer, if that is what you need, it is simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are going for? https://jsfiddle.net/4654eaue/10/

I added a background color to the container so that you can see it takes up all of it https://jsfiddle.net/4654eaue/11/

I used the css `calc()`

like this:

```
input{
    width: calc(100% - 125px);
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    height:23px;
}
```

So the input is now 100% of the 90% (minus the width of the `span`)

Comment: hohoho thank you so much, i never before used calc, this is great, thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu mateeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: @RS92 Yeah its a pretty awesome thing!

Answer (score 2):

Well, try this :

There is [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gcva29um/3/)

I remove those `spans` but add one `div` and place `input` inside him. I had to change input `height` to `29px` ... using `display:table;` for container and for `img` and `div` `table-cell` .... if that's ok for You.

html :

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://science.psu.edu/alert/icons/video-iconSmall.png">
<div><input type="text" name="fname" value="John Doe" disabled class="profileusername bordertop"></div>
<img src="http://science.psu.edu/alert/icons/video-iconSmall.png">
    </div>
```

css :

```
.container{
    width:90%;
    display:table;
}
.container div {display:table-cell; width:100%; vertical-align:top; }
input{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:29px;
    vertical-align:top;

}
.container img{
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    background-color:gray;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**Update :**

There is example where `input` `fixed` `height` is avoided. Much better solution in comparing with above one. Simple, `input` `height` will fit to `img` `height` and rest of total `width` of container.

[**New fiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gcva29um/4/)

Comment: thats nice, but how to set to be inline to top?

Comment: then `input` goes about 1 or 2px down... I try that but can't find solution.

Comment: @RS92 I update my answer with fiddle example. now using `vertical-align:top;` but then i had to put `margin-top:-2px` for `input`

Comment: It's almost there, wrap each image into div would be it [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gcva29um/1/)

Comment: @Pangloss great... my first solution, which I abandon... why? i don't know. maybe to avoid to much elements.

Comment: Just add `vertical-algin:top` to the div for your first solution [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gcva29um/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `display:table`, `display:table-row`, `display:table-cell`

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span><img src="http://science.psu.edu/alert/icons/video-iconSmall.png"></span>
        <input type="text" name="fname" value="John Doe" disabled class="profileusername bordertop">
        <span><img src="http://science.psu.edu/alert/icons/video-iconSmall.png"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:90%;
    display: table;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
input{
    vertical-align:top;
    display:table-cell;
    height:23px;
    width: 100%;
}
span img{
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
span{
    vertical-align:top;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:grey;
    width: 49px;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/4654eaue/4/